# ¿Como obtener la informacion de un Request en Laravel?

Tags: jquery, laravel, ajax

En una pagina de Wordpress, inclui un script que obtiene un poco de informacion de unos formularios y se manda a una ruta de mi app de Laravel. La parte que importa de ese script es la siguiente:

```
var data = JSON.stringify(data);
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: 'json',
    url: "https://myurl.com/api/contact",
    data: data,
    contentType: "application/json",
});
```

En el controlador de Laravel, deseo extraer la informacion de ese request. Al guardar el request en la base de datos

```
class MyController extends Controller
{
    public function contact(Request $request) {
        $test = new Email;
        $test->field1 = json_encode($request);
        $test->field2 = $request;
        $test->save();
    }
}
```

El resultado que obtengo en field1 es

```
{"attributes":{},"request":{},"query":{},"server":{},"files":{},"cookies":{},"headers":{}}
```

Y el resultado que obtengo en field2 es

```
POST /api/wordpress/contact HTTP/1.1
 Accept:            application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
 Accept-Encoding:   gzip, deflate, br
 Accept-Language:   en-US,en;q=0.9
 Content-Length:    47
 Content-Type:      application/json
 Host:              d2b95140a775.ngrok.io
 Origin:            https://www.my.url
 Referer:           https://www.my.url/
 Sec-Fetch-Dest:    empty
 Sec-Fetch-Mode:    cors
 Sec-Fetch-Site:    cross-site
 Sec-Gpc:           1
 User-Agent:        Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.101 Safari/537.36
 X-Forwarded-For:   190.148.52.140
 X-Forwarded-Proto: https
 
 {"first_name":"firstname","lastname":"lastname","email":"myemail","phone":"phone"}
```

Lo unico que deseo hacer es obtener la informacion de la persona, la que viene hasta abajo, como sus nombres, telefono, etc. ¿como puedo obtener esa informacion a partir del objeto Request que llega a mi controlador?

Comment: Cada vez que creas un objeto Request, esté tendrá varios datos que Laravel evalúa, si quieres obtener solo la información de los datos que mandaste en el Request, solo tienes que hacer `$request->all();` y eso te devolverá un array de todos los datos que enviaste.

Comment: Está explicado en la documentación https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/requests#input